# Validation isn't working and now my site is broke as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had the basics "insert numbers, output answer" aspect of this working fine. But i need to put validation into the site so only certain things work. My site upon putting validation in, stopped working altogether, and i dont fully understand why or whats going on.

JS fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ufs869wu/

HTML:

```
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
            <label for="txtAge">Age:</label>
            <input type="text" class="txtInput" id="txtAge" value="0"/><p id="ageRes"></p>
            <br/>
            <label for="txtMass">Mass in Lbs:</label>
            <input type="text" class="txtInput" id="txtMass" value="0"/>
            <br/>
            <label for="txtHinch">Height in Inches:</label>
            <input type="text" class="txtInput" id="txtHinch" value="0"/>
            <br/>
            <input type="button" id="btnCalc" value="Calculate"/>
            <p id="result2">Result</p>
        </form>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script src="BMI.js"></script>
</body>
```

and JS

```
// JavaScript Document

$(function () {
    //Identify Variables
    var txtMass, txtHinch, result;
    var isValid = $('#form1').validate().form();
    // attach event listener to the toggle button's click event



    $('#btnCalc').click(function () {

        //Set validator
            $.validator.setDefaults({
            errorElement: "span",
            errorClass: "form_error",
            errorPlacement: function(error,element){
                error.insertAfter(element)
                }
            });
            $.extend($.validator.messages,{
            required: "* Required field"
            });
            //Set Validation perameters
            $("#form1").validate({
            rules: {
                txtAge: {
                    required: true,
                    range: [1, 120],
                    digits: true
                },
                txtMass: {
                        require: true,
                        digits: true
                },
                txtHinch: {
                    requre: true,
                    digits: true
                }
            }
            });

        if (isValid) {

            //Set Age range for form accuracy
            if (txtAge < 16 || txtAage > 80){
            //Output
            $('#ageRes').html('Results may not be accurate at your age')
            } else { (txtAge >= 16 || txtAge <= 80)
            $('#ageRes').html('Results should be accurate considering your age')




            //Equation for BMI
            result = ($('#txtMass').val() / ($('#txtHinch').val() * $('#txtHinch').val())) * 703;}

            //If - Else statement from output of BMI equation

            if (result < 16){
            $('#result2').html('Result: '+result.toFixed(1) + ' you are Severely underweight')
            } else if (result <=18 ){
            $('#result2').html('Result: '+result.toFixed(1) + ' you are underweight')
            } else if (result <=24){
            $('#result2').html('Result: '+result.toFixed(1) + ' you are healthy')
            } else if (result <= 30 ){
            $('#result2').html('Result: '+result.toFixed(1) + ' you are seriously overweight')
            } else if (result <=35 ){
            $('#result2').html('Result: '+result.toFixed(1) + ' you are obese')
            } else if (result <=40 ){
            $('#result2').html('Result: '+result.toFixed(1) + ' you are seriously obese')
            }

            }


    });


});
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling '$' before jquery has been loaded, and are getting a '$' is undefined error.
Try moving this line up into the head section of your html.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Also, are you including the jquery validation plugin somewhere?. I don't see it being included anywhere.